# alsamixer / pulseaudio choose internal mic over mic jack

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio, jack

I have laptops running Debian stretch / pulseaudio version 10.0-1 on which I'd like to choose the internal microphone over the mic jack.

When I plug my headphone which includes a microphone through the jack, only the microphone of the headset works and I don't find a way to switch to the built-in one.

```
$ amixer -c0 controls | grep -i mic
numid=16,iface=CARD,name='Internal Mic Phantom Jack'
numid=15,iface=CARD,name='Mic Jack'
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Boost Volume'
numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Playback Switch'
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Playback Volume'
numid=12,iface=MIXER,name='Internal Mic Boost Volume'
```

My sound card is an HDA Intel PCH on all my laptops.

I tried to disable the iface=CARD numid=15 but I get a Operation not permitted:

```
$ amixer -c0 cset numid=15 off
amixer: Control hw:0 element write error: Operation not permitted
```

EDIT:

As suggested in comment, I searched in pavucontrol and pulseaudio settings but can't find anything that solve my problem.

EDIT 2:

In order to have further information on the codecs, I paste the output of the `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` command:

```
Codec: Realtek ALC293
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0293
Subsystem Id: 0x17aa504b
Revision Id: 0x100003
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=5, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[2]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[3]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[4]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC293 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x57, nsteps=0x57, stepsize=0x02, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x2b 0x2b]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x57, nsteps=0x57, stepsize=0x02, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x05 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x07 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x3f, stepsize=0x02, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x97 0x97]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x24
Node 0x08 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x3f, stepsize=0x02, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x97 0x97]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x23
Node 0x09 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC293 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x3f, stepsize=0x02, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x3e 0x3e]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x22
Node 0x0a [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0b [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Dock Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Dock Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x00 0x00] [0x16 0x16] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 5
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d
Node 0x0c [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x0b
Node 0x0d [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x03 0x0b
Node 0x0e [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0f [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x10 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x11 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x12 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40040b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Internal Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x90a60130: [Fixed] Mic at Int N/A
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x13 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40040b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x40000000: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x14 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00010010: OUT EAPD
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x90170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x0c
Node 0x15 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=1, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0001001c: OUT HP EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x03211040: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Left
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x0c 0x0d*
Node 0x16 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0001001c: OUT HP EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x0c 0x0d*
Node 0x17 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000373c: IN OUT HP Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00: VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x0c* 0x0d
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Dock Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000024: IN Detect
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=03, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00003724: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x03a11020: [Jack] Mic at Ext Left
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=04, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000373c: IN OUT HP Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x0c* 0x0d
Node 0x1c [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400400: Mono
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x40738105: [N/A] Modem Hand at Ext N/A
    Conn = ATAPI, Color = Purple
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x5
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x06
Node 0x1f [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x20 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00040: Mono
  Processing caps: benign=0, ncoeff=90
Node 0x21 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x22 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 8
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d 0x0b 0x12* 0x13
Node 0x23 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 6
     0x18* 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d 0x0b
Node 0x24 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 2
     0x12* 0x13
Codec: Intel Skylake HDMI
Address: 2
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x80862809
Subsystem Id: 0x80860101
Revision Id: 0x100000
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0, Clock-stop-OK
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled KAE
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1a]: 16 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled KAE
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1a]: 16 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled KAE
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1a]: 16 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0b000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
  In-driver Connection: 3
     0x02 0x03 0x04
Node 0x06 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=1, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0b000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
  In-driver Connection: 3
     0x02 0x03 0x04
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=2, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=2, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0b000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
  In-driver Connection: 3
     0x02 0x03 0x04
Node 0x08 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
```

Edit 2:

I have more information about amixer, with and without the microphone plugged in as asked in comment, with these commands:

```
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 > /tmp/with_mic.codec0.dump
amixer -c0 contents > /tmp/with_mic.contents.dump
# unplug the microphone
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 > /tmp/without_mic.codec0.dump
amixer -c0 contents > /tmp/without_mic.contents.dump
```

Now if I do a diff on the codec0 files, I find as guessed by @dirkt that Node 0x22 switch from 0x12* to 0x1a.

```
Node 0x22 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
   Connection: 8
-     0x18 0x19 0x1a* 0x1b 0x1d 0x0b 0x12 0x13
+     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d 0x0b 0x12* 0x13
```

Now I find the only Auto-Mute Mode control, and disabled it.

```
$ amixer -c0 cget numid=11
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Auto-Mute Mode'
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=2
  ; Item #0 'Disabled'
  ; Item #1 'Enabled'
  : values=1
$ amixer -c0 cset numid=11 0
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Auto-Mute Mode'
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=2
  ; Item #0 'Disabled'
  ; Item #1 'Enabled'
  : values=0
```

I reproduce the dump with and without the microphone plugged in, but I still have in the difference the switch on the Node 22.

Comment: As you run Pulseaudio, try to change Pulseaudio settings, not ALSA settings. In the `pavucontrol` *Input* tab, are there Port settings for both the built-in mic and the headset mic? Can you switch?

Comment: Ok, got it for Pulseaudio. I can't find anything in pavucontrol in the Input tab. There's only "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" and the "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" in the Input Devices, and I can choose the port "Internal Microphone (unplugged)", "Microphone (plugged in)" and "Dock Microphone (unplugged)", but either choice is the Jack Microphone.

Comment: The interesting point is "unplugged" for the internal mic. When you unplug the jack mic, does that change? Does the internal mic work at all? Intel HDA normally works out of the box, but if your laptop does something funny, you can inspect the codec nodes with `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` (do both with jack mic unplugged and plugged, observer changes, too). This will need some amount of time to work through, though.

Comment: When I unplugged the Jack microphone, the internal microphone works perfectly. And I have in the Input Devices pannel the three choices: "Internal Microphone", "Microphone (unplugged)", "Dock Microphone (unplugged)". So it's like there's a switch between "Internal Microphone" and "Microphone" depending I have the Jack microphone plugged in or not. I edit the question with the output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: I'll explain some background, you still need to find out what goes wrong.

Intel HDA codecs are described as a graph of nodes, identified by hexadecimal values. You can use `codecgraph` to generate a graph as postscript file (though large graphs tend to be unreadable), but here's a crude textual representation:

```
N = Node  P = Pin  M = Mixer  I = Audio In  O = Audio Out  S = Selector


I07 <- S24 <- P12* P13
I08 <- S23 <- P18* P19 P1a P1b P1d  M0b
I09 <- S22 <- P18  P19 P1a P1b P1d  M0b  P12* P13   # capture stream = 1

O02 stream=1      # Speaker Playback Volume
O03 stream=1      # Headphone Playback Volume

O06               # Digital

M0b <- P18 P19 P1a P1b P1d
M0c <- O02 M0b    # (Speaker)
M0d <- O03 M0b    # (Headphone)

P12               # Fixd Mic     Int  / Internal Mic Boost Volume
P13               # N/A  Lin Out Ext  / Amp In   # = Line In?

P14 <- M0c        # Fixd Speaker Int      / Speaker Playback
P15 <- M0c  M0d*  # Jack HP Out  Ext Left / Headphone Playback
P16 <- M0c  M0d*  # N/A  Speaker Ext Rear / Headphone Playback

P18 <- M0c* M0d   # N/A  Speaker Ext Rear / Amp I/O
P19               # N/A  Speaker Ext Rear / Dock Mic Boost Volume
P1a               # Jack Mic     Ext Left / Mic Boost Volume
P1b <- M0c* M0d   # N/A  Speaker Ext Rear / Amp I/O

P1d               # N/A  Modem   Ext
P1e <- N06        # N/A  Speaker Ext Rear / Digital
```

I prefixed the nodes with their functions. Not all pins on the codec chip are connected to something, so just ignore those.

Just looking at recording, only node `09` is used for sound capture. Node `12` is the internal mic A/D converter, and node `1a` is the external microphone jack A/D converter. In your dump, selector node `22` selects node `12` for capture, so I assume the dump was made without the headphone plugged in.

Now we need to find out what changes when you plug the headset in. Please save both `codec#0` and the output of `amixer -c0 contents` in two temporary files, plug the headset in, and again save both in two different temporary files. Compare the files with `diff -u8` etc, identify the nodes and controls that change, and update your question.

My guess is that the selector node `22` will switch to `1a`, and there are possibly some mute and/or volume changes. However, I don't see an ALSA control at node `22`, so I don't know how to influence it via `amixer`.

Also, look for `Auto-Mute Mode` or anything similar in `amixer -c0 controls`. If you find anything, disable it (try all combinations if there are several), and do the whole thing again. This way we can find out what the default ALSA automute code tries to do when plugging the headphone, and find out if possibly something else influences the hardware.

**Edit**: If I read the ALSA source correctly, it's not the ALSA driver switching Node 0x22. So the next guess is that it's maybe some [System Management Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode) (SMM) feature in your laptop, but that's a wild guess. (You could try to disable SMM on boot to test if that's the case, out of curiosity, but then likely other features of your Laptop will also stop working).

Anyway, in my opinion there should be an ALSA mixer control at this node, so the user change the setting. Please upgrade your kernel to the newest version you can, and see if anything changes. If not, file a bug with the ALSA developers, maybe they can add a "quirk" (special case) to the driver for your laptop. Include the codec dump, and identify your Laptop as precisely as possible. An `lspci -nm` or similar may also help, if they need the subsystem id of the sound device.

In the meantime, you can use `hda-verb` to directly switch Node 0x22. In Debian, it's part of the package `alsa-utils` (and now apparently in `alsa-tools`). As root,

```
hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x22 GET_CONNECT_SEL 0
```

should show you the selected connection index (0-based) of Node 0x22. It should be either `2` or `6`. If that works, with

```
hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x22 SET_CONNECT_SEL 2
```

you can switch the node to index 2 (or to 6 with `6` as the last argument). Verify with contents of `codec#0` that it worked as intended. That should allow you to use the internal microphone after plugging in the headphone.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated the question. I confirm your guess on the switch of the Node 22. Even without the `Auto-Mute Mode` I still see the switch after on the `Node 22`.

Comment: Short note: If you don't find the `hda-verb` program in the `alsa-utils` package, try to install the `alsa-tools` package. I found it in the latter.